# JavaScript regex to validate complicated string

Tags: javascript, regex

Could you please help me to provide a RegEx pattern to validate a string which satisfy:

1. length from 4 to 10 (strictly)
2. first 3 characters must be string (A-Z a-z)
3. the remain characters must be number without `00` as prefix, I mean `ABC15` is passed but `ABC0015` is not.

This problem took me so much time and I have tried so many regex patterns, but I still have no solution for it.
Thank you so much.

Comment: Can you provide some examples you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this one:

```
/^[a-z]{3}(?!00)\d{1,7}$/i
```

Explanation:

```
/
^         Start
[a-z]{3}  Three letters.
(?!00)    Must NOT be followed by two zeros.
\d{1,7}   One to seven digits.
$         End.
/i        ignore case flag.
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy.

```
/^[a-z]{3}[1-9][0-9]{0,6}$/i
```

Matches three letters (case insensitive flag at the end), followed by one digit that is not zero, followed by up to six more digits (which may be zero).

Comment: No it isn't. It's (3 letters) + (1 digit) + (up to 6 digits), which has 4 as a minimum and 10 as a max.

Comment: This pattern also matches `AAA4444444444444444444`, because of the missing `^` and `$`. Also, it allows consecutive zeros ater `[a-z]{3}`.

Comment: Whoopsie. Usually I don't forget things like that. And I wasn't sure if it should allow `ABC0123` (ie. one leading zero) or not... The question didn't really clear that one up.